# Asynchronous function is not working in order of process

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm working with **asynchronous javascript** in NodeJS. I have a function, that modifies it's parameters and then **resolve** and **emits to SocketIO client**. The problem is, the function doesn't process the lines in order, it makes some process first and some process after it, I think it is just about asynchronous JavaScript problem, but I can't understand what to do for solve this.

My function,

```
const processStylesAndImages = (target, targetSlug, id, socket, styles, images, protocol, CSS, DOM) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let { coverage } = await CSS.takeCoverageDelta();
        let { nodes } = await DOM.getFlattenedDocument({ depth: -1 });
        styles = styles.filter(style => !style.isInline && style.sourceURL.trim().length > 0);
        for(let style of styles) {
            style.mediaQueries = [];
            let m;
            while(m = mediaQueryRegex.exec(style.css)) {
                style.mediaQueries.push({
                    startOffset: m.index,
                    endOffset: m.index + m[0].length,
                    rule: style.css.slice(m.index, m.index + m[0].length),
                    used: true,
                    rules: []
                });
            }
            style.used = [];
            while(m = charsetRegex.exec(style.css)) {
                style.used.push({
                    startOffset: m.index,
                    endOffset: m.index + m[0].length,
                    used: true,
                    styleSheetId: style.styleSheetId
                });
            }
            while(m = importRegexVariable.exec(style.css)) {
                style.used.push({
                    startOffset: m.index,
                    endOffset: m.index + m[0].length,
                    used: true,
                    styleSheetId: style.styleSheetId
                });
            }
            let fontFaces = [];
            while(m = fontFaceRegex.exec(style.css)) {
                fontFaces.push(m);
            }
            fontFaces.forEach((m, index) => {
                let pushed = false;
                let props = css.parse(style.css.slice(m.index, m.index + m[0].length)).stylesheet.rules[0].declarations;
                let fontFamily;
                let fontWeight = null;
                props.forEach(prop => {
                    if(prop.property == 'font-family') {
                        if(prop.value.startsWith("'") || prop.value.startsWith('"')) {
                            prop.value = prop.value.slice(1);
                        }
                        if(prop.value.endsWith("'") || prop.value.endsWith('"')) {
                            prop.value = prop.value.slice(0, -1);
                        }
                        prop.value = prop.value.toLowerCase();
                        fontFamily = prop.value;
                    } else if(prop.property == 'font-weight') {
                        fontWeight = prop.value;
                    }
                });
                if(fontWeight == null || 'normal') fontWeight = 400;
                if(style.sourceURL == 'https://www.webmedya.com.tr/css/font-awesome.min.css') console.log(fontFamily, fontWeight);
                nodes.forEach(async (node, nodeIndex) => {
                    let { computedStyle } = await CSS.getComputedStyleForNode({ nodeId: node.nodeId });
                    computedStyle = computedStyle.filter(item => {
                        return (item.name == 'font-family' || item.name == 'font-weight') && (item.value !== '' || typeof(item.value) !== 'undefined');
                    });
                    let elementFontFamily;
                    let elementFontWeight;
                    computedStyle.forEach(compute => {
                        if(compute.name == 'font-family' && compute.value !== '' && typeof(compute.value) !== 'undefined') {
                            elementFontFamily = compute.value.toLowerCase();
                        } else if(compute.name == 'font-weight') {
                            if(compute.value !== '' && typeof(compute.value) !== 'undefined') {
                                if(compute.value == 'normal') {
                                    elementFontWeight = 400;
                                } else {
                                    elementFontWeight = compute.value;
                                }
                            } else {
                                elementFontWeight = 400;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if(elementFontFamily && elementFontWeight) {
                        if(elementFontFamily.includes(fontFamily) && (elementFontWeight == fontWeight)) {
                            if(!pushed) {
                                //console.log(m);
                                style.used.push({
                                    startOffset: m.index,
                                    endOffset: m.index + m[0].length,
                                    used: true,
                                    styleSheetId: style.styleSheetId
                                });
                                pushed = true;
                                console.log('Pushed', style.css.slice(m.index, m.index + m[0].length));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log('BBBBBBBBBBBBB');
            console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAA');
            let parsedSourceURL = url.parse(style.sourceURL.trim());
            if(parsedSourceURL.protocol === null && parsedSourceURL.host === null) {
                if(style.sourceURL.trim().startsWith('/')) {
                    style.sourceURL = `${target}${style.sourceURL.trim()}`;
                } else {
                    style.sourceURL = `${target}/${style.sourceURL.trim()}`;
                }
            };
            style.parentCSS = "-1";
            style.childCSSs = [];
            style.childCSSs = getImports(style.css, style.sourceURL.trim(), target);
            coverage.forEach(item => {
                if(item.styleSheetId.trim() == style.styleSheetId.trim())
                    style.used.push(item);
            });
            style.mediaQueries.forEach((mediaQuery, index) => {
                style.used.forEach((usedRule, usedIndex) => {
                    if(usedRule.startOffset > mediaQuery.startOffset && usedRule.endOffset < mediaQuery.endOffset) {
                        style.mediaQueries[index].rules.push(style.used[usedIndex]);
                        style.used[usedIndex] = false;
                    }
                });
            });
            style.used = style.used.filter(item => {
                return item !== false;
            });
            style.mediaQueries = style.mediaQueries.filter(item => {
                return item.rules.length > 0;
            });
            style.mediaQueries.forEach((mediaQuery, index) => {
                mediaQuery.rules.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset);
            });
            style.used = style.used.concat(style.mediaQueries);
            delete style.mediaQueries;
            style.used.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset);
            let compressedCss = "";
            if(style.used.length > 0) {
                style.used.forEach(usedRule => {
                    if(usedRule.rule && usedRule.rules.length > 0) {
                        let queryRule = usedRule.rule.match(/@media[^{]+/)[0];
                        compressedCss += queryRule + '{';
                        usedRule.rules.forEach(item => {
                            compressedCss += style.css.slice(item.startOffset, item.endOffset);
                        });
                        compressedCss += '}';
                    } else {
                        compressedCss += style.css.slice(usedRule.startOffset, usedRule.endOffset);
                    }
                });
            };
            style.compressedCss = compressedCss;
        }
        console.log('CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');
        styles = preTraverse(styles, targetSlug, id);
        debug('CSS Dosyaları İşlendi!');
        fs.readFile(`./data/${targetSlug}/${id}/cimg/statistics.json`, async (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                await CSS.stopRuleUsageTracking();
                await protocol.close();
                if(typeof(styles) !== 'undefined' && styles.length > 0) {
                    debug('IMG Dosyaları İşlendi!');
                    socket.emit('log', { stage: 6, images, data, styles });
                    resolve({ images, data, styles });
                } else {
                    debug('IMG Dosyaları İşlendi!');
                    socket.emit('log', { stage: 6, images, data, styles: [] });
                    resolve({ images, data, styles: [] });
                };
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            };
        });
    });
};
```

Results when the functions starts for some parameters,

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
fontawesome 400
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
Pushed @font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
Pushed @font-face{font-family:open sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Open Sans Light'),local('OpenSans-Light'),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTa-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F}
Pushed @font-face{font-family:open sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Open Sans Light'),local('OpenSans-Light'),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F,U+0490-0491,U+04B0-04B1,U+2116}
```

The expected result is,

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
fontawesome 400
Pushed @font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
Pushed @font-face{font-family:open sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Open Sans Light'),local('OpenSans-Light'),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTa-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F}
Pushed @font-face{font-family:open sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Open Sans Light'),local('OpenSans-Light'),url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F,U+0490-0491,U+04B0-04B1,U+2116}
BBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

The function is skips the **for loop** at line 6 in JSFiddle. It behaves like **asynchronous process**, but I want to it behave like **synchronous**.

Thanks!

Comment: Alright @CertainPerformance, thanks!

Comment: A couple of anti-patterns here. -> `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)`  and  `nodes.forEach(async (node, nodeIndex)`  forEach has no notion of promises, unless you push into an array and `Promise.all` them.

Comment: Yes, @Keith, you are right. The problem is by `array.forEach(async ...)`, now my code is working but what is the proof of this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by proof, foreach is just a synchrouse looping construct, more info here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your time! I'm so glad! Have a good day sir!

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572) You should put the `new Promise` wrapper at most around the `fs.readFile()` call, and then only call `resolve`/`reject` in the callback but do nothing else. Or just use `fs.promise` right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await the `new Promise((res, rej) => {` promise on line `39` in your fiddle. You create a promise with `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers which you run it within your loop, but don't `await` it. Meaning, the promise is triggered, but the code continues to the next iteration already.

So try to add `await` in front of that `new Promise(...)` on line `39` and run it.

Comment: I updated the function code. I did tried your advice but, it didn't work :/ Can you check new code, please?

Comment: I can't see the new `await new Promise()` but I did notice also you have `nodes.forEach(async (node, nodeIndex)`. `.forEach` does not handle `async` perse in a correct sequence. Try to replace any `foreach(async ...)` occurrence with a normal `for` loop. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Damn son! Thanks buddy, it works fine but what is the real proof of this `array.foreach(async ...)`to `for(item of array)` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "what is the real proof " ? So I can elaborate :)

Comment: So, why the asynchronous functions don't work on `array.forEach()` loop @Ian Segers ?

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN : So you can run an `async` function in `forEach()` but the `forEach()` function does not wait to the completion of a promise or async function that you provided. The `.forEach()` was originally created to run synchronous functions. So what happens now is that, when you have an async function for `.forEach` the async function is "triggered" but then the `forEach()` will already continue to the next item of the array. As you have multiple functions triggered after each other without waiting on the previous, its hard to guess the order they complete in. Hope that helps :)